# need help identifing parts

Tags: identification, pins, thermistor, socket

The first Green bit is a thermistor out of a fluke 374 clamp meter, but cant find the manufacture from the logo or what the number means.

The other is a socket pin from a single wire connector, its very close to molex but it only has one retention tab  11mm long barrel, 18.5mm oal, and 2mm pin bore

[image]

[image]

[image]

[More images.](https://m.imgur.com/a/LUMum0R)

Answer (score 2):

The thermistor is made by amperon. Probably the [MZ1 series](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=zh-CN&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=http://en.ampron.com/prod_view.aspx%3FTypeId%3D67%26Id%3D182%26FId%3Dt3:67:3&xid=17259,15700021,15700186,15700191,15700253,15700256,15700259&usg=ALkJrhi0dSvjmRuI8Q2qps9jKsJx1uKulw).

I would guess that the connector is also molex.

Answer (score 1):

The socket is a TE connectivity commercial MATE-N-LOK 20-14 AWG Brass TE Part # 60620-1